# Assign Mouse Buttons in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mouse, button

Does anyone know how to bind extra mouse buttons to commands in visual studio 2008?  There used to be a "powertoy" that let you do it for visual studio 2003, but I can't find an equivalent for 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While AutoHotKey was interesting, it doesn't really do what I want to do, which is map buttons to keys in an application-specific context.

I ended up finding this add-in:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MouseNavi.aspx

which I just modified and threw into the AddIns directory for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: BTW I thought I'd continue the trend of one-word answers :D

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still looking for a solution that will work in any version of Visual Studio (as I was), I found [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm).

You can map your commands to whatever keyboard shortcut you like and then use X-Mouse Button Control to send those keystrokes only to devenv.exe.

First you'll have to add an application profile for devenv.exe. Then, to map the keystrokes, just select "Simulated Keys" in the dropdown box next to the mouse button you want. Follow the prompts to set the keystrokes, and you're all set.

Comment: Great. It took me a while to find "Simulated keys" entry between all those predefined actions, but after that configuring it for VS was easy.

Comment: I'm glad you found this useful. I edited my original post to include some useful instructions for setting it up.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSMouseBindings)

Comment: Thanks, but that's the Visual Studio 2003 plug-in that I was talking about.  It doesn't work with Visual Studio 2008.  Anything else?

Comment: I saw that the Release Date was May 13 2008 so I assumed it had been updated.