# Fast way to insert include guard in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to automatically insert [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) into newly created header files in Visual Studio 2012. Is there any predefined snippet for this purpose?

EDIT: I'm aware of #pragma once and its wide support by compilers. But our coding style forces me to use include guards.

Comment: Create a rather simple VS macro - see my answer below. Then you can assign a hotkey to it.

Answer (score 8):

In visual studio 2012 use the key combinations

```
Ctrl+K,Ctrl+S
```

It allows you to surround selected code with code snippets such as:

`#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `if`, `class`, `do`, `enum`, and many more

.. or specify your own:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Comment: ah I missed the VS 2012 part - I tried it in VS2010, and it tells me "...bound to command Surround With which is currently not available)"... so it seems they added it in between! thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 1):

`#pragma once`?

But no, I'm not aware of anything that automatically inserts the `#ifndef`, etc. for you.

Comment: Pragma once is default and not really relevant to question. It's already mentioned in question.

Comment: @saurabheights: Note that the part in the question was added _after_ this answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're tagging C++, you should add classes by the built-in wizard. The wizard creates #pragma once directives. This is even available for other compilers: [#pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) so you don't break plattform cross compatibility.

What you can do, however, is to create a VS macro like this one:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System

Public Module HeaderGuard
    Sub InsertHeaderGuard()
        Dim filename As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Name
        filename = filename.ToUpper().Replace("."c, "_"c)
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "#ifndef " + filename
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "#define " + filename
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine(2)
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "#endif /* " + filename + " */"
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Unless one is using Visual Studio 2012 (or newer), where macro support has been removed.

Comment: Well, that's not too nice. But it may be considered to make an add-on out of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027485/alternative-to-macros-in-visual-studio-2012 (haven't tried that though)

Comment: @RolfKristensen: Have they really removed macro support? How dumb is that! I created loads of macros in VS2005 that did things like set up new files with #ifdef style guards, create classes and functions with comments. Add-ons are just too much effort to create compared to a macro. Does this also mean the record temporary macro is gone too? VS used to be really good but it seems to be getting worse with each release. Currently moving to emacs.

Comment: As it looks, recording macros is also gone. Didn't know this too. Currently I'm looking at Visualstudiogallery (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) whether there might be an extension that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Assist X you can remove your `#pragma once` if present, select the rest of the text, right click and `Surround with (VA)` => `#ifdef guard in a header`. If you don't like the default you can override it going to `VASSISTX` menu and selecting `Tools` => `Edit VA Snippets...`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey). Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578675/assign-mouse-buttons-in-visual-studio-2008/578900#578900) to an simular question.